# Why does the SensorEvent doesn't respond well on Bitmap and has a null?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an app that involves a CameraX API and Bitmap, My goal is to make the camera not only to capture a simple image, but to take the image and to draw a Watermark text on top of the image before making the file, however the Azimuth, Pitch and Roll shows as null results when the bitmap is finished, here is the result of it. [![The actual output of the JPEG file. If I didn't explained it correctly or made a mistake while explaining, please do let me know as soon as possible, also having some questions, I'll answer them. Thank you in advance.
[image]

I'm gonna give additional meaning of the image and translate from Bulgarian to English and what it stands for:
Посока -> Direction: where(West,South,North,East) Azimuth,
Наклон -> Tilting: Pitch, Roll

```
private val mSensorEvent: SensorEvent? = null

override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {

   //Azimuth, Pitch and Roll
   val azimuthWMText = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mSensorEvent?.values?.get(0))
   val pitchWMText = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mSensorEvent?.values?.get(1))
   val rollWMText = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mSensorEvent?.values?.get(2))

   //Bitmap that contains the addWatermark method and detecting the new photo path that is been taken and implements the watermark
   //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.toString(), BitmapFactory.Options()) -> through File
   //resources, R.layout.activity_preview_photo, BitmapFactory.Options() -> through resources
   val originalBitmap = AddWatermark().addWatermark(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.toString(), BitmapFactory.Options()),
                        firstWatermarkText = "Дължина: $longitudeWM${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}, Ширина: $latitudeWM${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}",
                        secondWatermarkText = "Височина: ${altitudeWM}м, Ориентация: $orientationWM",
                        thirdWatermarkText = "Точност: Хоризонтална: ${hozAccuracyWM}м, Вертикална: ${verAccuracyWM}м",
                        fourthWatermarkText = "Посока: where $azimuthWMText${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}",
                        fifthWatermarkText = "Наклон: pitchTilt $pitchWMText${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}, rollTilt $rollWMText${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}",
                        sixthWatermarkText = "Дата и Час: $dateTimeFormatWMText",
                        AddWatermark.WatermarkOptions(
                            AddWatermark.Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                            textSizeToWidthRation = 0.017f,
                            paddingToWidthRatio = 0.03f,
                            Color.parseColor("#FF0000"),
                            shadowColor = Color.BLACK,
                            strokeOutline = null,
                            typeface = null
                        )
                    )
                    previewView.bitmap.let { originalBitmap }

                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(photoFile)
                    originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream)
                    outputStream.flush()
                    outputStream.close()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@CameraActivity,
                        "Обработването и запазено успешно! Запазено е в: $photoFile",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
}
```

The watermark class code:

```
class AddWatermark : AppCompatActivity() {
    //Adding watermark method is here for declaring on to the top
    fun addWatermark(
        bitmap: Bitmap,
        firstWatermarkText: String,
        secondWatermarkText: String,
        thirdWatermarkText: String,
        fourthWatermarkText: String,
        fifthWatermarkText: String,
        sixthWatermarkText: String,
        options: WatermarkOptions = WatermarkOptions()): Bitmap {
        val result = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        //val strokePaint = Paint()

        //We are including the Enum class and connecting with the data class WatermarkOptions variable
        paint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            //We include the alignment LEFT from Enum class and connecting with Paint variable
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT

            //We include the alignment RIGHT from Enum class and connecting with Paint variable
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }

        /*strokePaint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT

            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }

         */

        //We connect the new textSize variable with the bitmap width(default is 0) and we multiply with the WatermarkOption's textSize
        val textSize = result.width * options.textSizeToWidthRation
        //Connecting the Paint textSize variable with the new textSize variable
        paint.textSize = textSize//70.5f
        //Connecting the Paint color variable with the WatermarkOptions textColor
        paint.color = options.textColor
        //If the shadowColor of the WMOptions is not null, then we make it as a Paint shadowLayer variable
        if (options.shadowColor != null) {
            paint.setShadowLayer( 2.5f, 0f, 0f, options.shadowColor)
        }

        /*if (options.strokeOutline != null) {
            strokePaint.textSize = textSize//72f
            strokePaint.color = options.strokeOutline
            strokePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokePaint.strokeWidth = 4.17f
        }

         */

        //If typeface of the WMOptions is not null,we make paint typeface variable and connecting with the WMOptions variable
        if (options.typeface != null) {
            paint.typeface = options.typeface
        }
        //We connect the new padding variable with the bitmap width(default is 0) and multiply with WMOptions padding
        val padding = result.width * options.paddingToWidthRatio

        //Create a variable that has something to do with the coordinates method
        val coordinates = calculateCoordinates(
            firstWatermarkText,
            secondWatermarkText,
            thirdWatermarkText,
            fourthWatermarkText,
            fifthWatermarkText,
            sixthWatermarkText,
            paint,
            options,
            canvas.width,
            canvas.height,
            padding)
        /**drawText text as a Watermark, using Canvas**/
        //canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, strokePaint)
        //canvas.drawText(secondWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 240f, strokePaint) //We change the Y horizontal coordinates by typing the float number
        //canvas.drawText(thirdWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 310f, strokePaint)
        //canvas.drawText(fourthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 380f, strokePaint)
        //canvas.drawText(fifthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 450f, strokePaint)

        when (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            //Android 11
            30 -> {
                canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)
                canvas.drawText(secondWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 240f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(thirdWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 310f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(fourthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 380f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(fifthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 450f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(sixthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 520f, paint)
            }

            //Android 9
            28 -> {
                canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)
                canvas.drawText(secondWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 240f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(thirdWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 310f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(fourthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 380f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(fifthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 450f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(sixthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 520f, paint)
            }

            //Android 5.0
            21 -> {
                canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)
                canvas.drawText(secondWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 270f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(thirdWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 330f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(fourthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 420f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(fifthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 480f, paint)
                canvas.drawText(sixthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 540f, paint)
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    //This it he corner alignment calculation method and using it on the drawText
    private fun calculateCoordinates(
        firstWatermarkText: String,
        secondWatermarkText: String,
        thirdWatermarkText: String,
        fourthWatermarkText: String,
        fifthWatermarkText: String,
        sixthWatermarkText: String,
        paint: Paint,
        options: WatermarkOptions,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        padding: Float
    ): PointF {
        val x = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> {
                padding
            }
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                width - padding
            }
        }

        val y = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                height - padding
            }
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT -> {
                val bounds = Rect()

                paint.getTextBounds(firstWatermarkText, 0, firstWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(secondWatermarkText, 0, secondWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(thirdWatermarkText, 0, thirdWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(fourthWatermarkText, 0, fourthWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(fifthWatermarkText, 0, fifthWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(sixthWatermarkText, 0, sixthWatermarkText.length, bounds)

                val textHeight = bounds.height()
                textHeight + padding
            }
        }
        return PointF(x, y)
    }

    enum class Corner {
        TOP_LEFT,
        TOP_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT
    }

    data class WatermarkOptions(
        val corner: Corner = Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        val textSizeToWidthRation: Float = 0.04f,
        val paddingToWidthRatio: Float = 0.03f,
        @ColorInt val textColor: Int = Color.parseColor("#FFC800"),
        @ColorInt val shadowColor: Int? = Color.BLACK,
        @ColorInt val strokeOutline: Int? = Color.BLACK,
        val typeface: Typeface? = null
    )
}
```

Comment: and how do you obtain `mSensorEvent`? in posted code it is declared as `null` so everything is beahving like expected

Comment: That is true, but if I switch it to a ```non-null``` also known as ```!!```, it will display in logcat the ```NullPointerException```. Which will make the app shut down. I obtain ```mSensorEvent?``` in order to initialize it somehow.

Comment: but it is `null`. you are declaring it as `null` and never update this value, not in posted snippets

Comment: Ok, what should I do ? Like I literally have no ideas how to make it display. If I remove the ```null``` initialization and put it as a lateinit, there is nothing I could initialize it to and will give me the ```lateinit property mSensorEvent has not been initialized```

Comment: in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion) you ahve some guide how to obtain `SensorEvent`s

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out my issue and instead of using a new `mSensorEvent`, I used the sensor event inside "onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?)" instead and recasting all the lateinit variables, so here is the answer to my question:

```
private var azimuthDegree: Double = 0.0
private var currentAzimuth: Double = 0.0

private var currentPitch: Double = 0.0
private var currentRoll: Double = 0.0

//'dirs' is the directions array list of type String and 'currentDirection' will be used for recasting
private var dirs = ArrayList<String>()
private lateinit var currentDirection: String

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        actionBar?.hide()

        //Makes a register to the listener about the default sensor for the Azimuth orientation type
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        //If it fails, to unregister the listener from it's sensor
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

/**The sensor method initializes the type sensors and calculates the gravity and geomagnetic field**/
    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        //Portrait measurements - Correct by default
        try {
            val windowOrientation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation

            //Azimuth
            degreeAzimuth = event!!.values[0].toDouble()
            val azimuthTxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.azimuthText)

            //This makes sure that the calculations between Pitch and Roll, doesn't switch places when the orientation is turned between Portrait and Landscape by default
            var degreeRoll: Double
            var degreePitch: Double

            if (windowOrientation == 1 || windowOrientation == 3) {
                degreeRoll = event.values[1].toDouble()
                degreePitch = event.values[2].toDouble()
            } else {
                degreeRoll = event.values[2].toDouble()
                degreePitch = event.values[1].toDouble()
            }

            //Orientation calculations for the Pitch in degrees, when it's Portrait, Landscape, Reverse Portrait and Reverse Landscape, to stay the same case with each and every value
            when (windowOrientation) {
                Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
                    degreePitch += 90
                }

                1 -> {
                    if (abs(degreeRoll) > 90) {
                        degreePitch -= 90
                        degreeRoll = if (degreeRoll < 0)
                            -(180 + degreeRoll)
                        else
                            180 - degreeRoll
                    } else {
                        degreePitch = 90 - degreePitch
                    }
                }

                2 -> {
                    degreePitch = if (degreePitch < 90)
                        90 - degreePitch
                    else
                        -(degreePitch - 90)
                    degreeRoll = -degreeRoll
                }


                3 -> {
                    if (abs(degreeRoll) > 90) {
                        degreePitch = -(90 + degreePitch)
                        degreeRoll = if (degreeRoll < 0)
                            -(180 + degreeRoll)
                        else
                            180 - degreeRoll
                    } else {
                        degreePitch += 90
                        degreeRoll = -degreeRoll
                    }
                }
            }

            /*Calculations when Azimuth is been turned with a new orientation, that "azimuth"
            is the new variable for making azimuth and window display to be times 90 degrees.
            After that we change the new variable "azimuth" to the dirs array list.*/

//Direction display from the array list from 1 to 9 elements
            val where = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.direction_text)
            dirs = arrayListOf(
                "North",
                "North East",
                "East",
                "South East",
                "South",
                "South West",
                "West",
                "North West",
                "North"
            )

            // We change the "azimuth" variable here, along with it's calculations.
            var azimuth = degreeAzimuth + (windowOrientation * 90)
            when (windowOrientation) {
                //Portrait
                Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
                //Landscape
                Surface.ROTATION_90 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
                //Reverse Portrait
                Surface.ROTATION_180 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
                //Reverse Landscape
                Surface.ROTATION_270 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
            }

            currentDirection = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]

            currentAzimuth = azimuth
            val azimuthText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.azimuthText)
            azimuthText.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, currentAzimuth)

            currentPitch = degreePitch
            val pitchText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pitchText)
            pitchText.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, currentPitch)

            currentRoll = degreeRoll
            val rollText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rollText)
            rollText.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, currentRoll)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

currentAzimuth, currentPith, currentRoll - Those are recasting and using them as an end result

azimuthDegree - This is used for calculation reasons only in order to make for every orientation of the display surface

Also the other way around since the `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` is deprecated from Java, the suggest way is this:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        actionBar?.hide()

        //Makes a register to the listener about the default sensor for the Azimuth gravity and magnetic field
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
    }

    /**The sensor method initializes the type sensors and calculates the gravity and geomagnetic field**/
    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        //Portrait measurements - Correct by default
        try {
            val windowOrientation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation

            //Announcing the alpha for timing
            val alpha = 0.97f
            //The Sensor Event selects a type between Accelerometer and Magnetic Field
            when (event!!.sensor.type) {
                Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER -> {
                    mGravity[0] = alpha * mGravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0]
                    mGravity[1] = alpha * mGravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1]
                    mGravity[2] = alpha * mGravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2]
                }

                Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD -> {
                    mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0]
                    mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1]
                    mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2]
                }
            }
            val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)
            val inclinationMatrix = FloatArray(9)

            val success: Boolean = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, inclinationMatrix, mGravity, mGeomagnetic)
            
            if (success) {
                //Azimuth
                degreeAzimuth = event!!.values[0].toDouble()
                val azimuthTxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.azimuthText)

                //This makes sure that the calculations between Pitch and Roll, doesn't switch places when the orientation is turned between Portrait and Landscape by default
                var degreeRoll: Double
                var degreePitch: Double

                if (windowOrientation == 1 || windowOrientation == 3) {
                    degreeRoll = event.values[1].toDouble()
                    degreePitch = event.values[2].toDouble()
                } else {
                    degreeRoll = event.values[2].toDouble()
                    degreePitch = event.values[1].toDouble()
                }

// We change the "azimuth" variable here, along with it's calculations.
            var azimuth = degreeAzimuth + (windowOrientation * 90)
            when (windowOrientation) {
                //Portrait
                Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
                //Landscape
                Surface.ROTATION_90 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
                //Reverse Portrait
                Surface.ROTATION_180 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
                //Reverse Landscape
                Surface.ROTATION_270 -> {
                    if (azimuth > 360) {
                        azimuth -= 360
                    }
                    azimuthTxt.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth)
                    where.text = dirs[((azimuth + 22.5) / 45.0).toInt()]
                }
            }

            currentAzimuth = azimuth
            val azimuthText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.azimuthText)
            azimuthText.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, currentAzimuth)

            currentPitch = degreePitch
            val pitchText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pitchText)
            pitchText.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, currentPitch)

            currentRoll = degreeRoll
            val rollText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rollText)
            rollText.text = resources.getString(R.string.value_format, currentRoll)
            }
       }
```

Then `onImageSave()` method when assign the AddWatermark class within it as it follows:

```
val originalBitmap = AddWatermark().addWatermark(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.absolutePath),
                            firstWatermarkText = "Azimuth:$dirs, $currentAzimuth",
                            secondWatermarkText = "Pitch: $currentPitch, Roll: $currentRoll",
                            AddWatermark.WatermarkOptions(
                                AddWatermark.Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                                textSizeToWidthRatio = 0.017f,
                                paddingToWidthRatio = 0.03f,
                                textColor = Color.parseColor("#FF0000"),
                                shadowColor = null,
                                typeface = null
                            )
                        )
                        viewFinder.bitmap.let { originalBitmap }

                        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(photoFile.toString())
                        originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream)
                        outputStream.flush()
                        outputStream.close()
```